# WSO2 BAM program

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I want to write my own code in WSO2 BAM. I had gone through samples provided.

Now I want to know how should I write those JAVA classes. What approach should I apply. What all are necessary files. What IDE should be used.

I want to create project and run it on WSO2 BAM and need guidance on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Java Classes are you talking about? In WSO2 BAM you don't need to write Java code. You only need to write Hive queries which are similar to SQL queries to program the BAM. Those queries will create Hadoop map-reduce jobs inside. Read [docs](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/WSO2+Business+Activity+Monitor+Documentation) for more details.